# Show HashMap from session to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

Please help to show this map in the JSP using select tag.

What am I doing wrong?

```
...
Map<String, String> usersEmail = new HashMap<String, String>();
...
request.setAttribute("usersEmail", usersEmail);
....
<select name="emails">
    <c:forEach items="${usersEmail}" var="email">
        <option value="${email.key}">${email.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: What happens when this JSP is executed?

Comment: In the result I have empty select tag

Comment: Then the map is probably empty. Or you forgot to declare the core taglib. Check the generated HTML code in the page source.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have define Tag lib for hasmap. And define the attribute type to java.utill.map.